# Regex replacement with multiple occurances and different values within a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this code:

```
<object height="510"   width="650">height="510"width="650">
```

or this code:

```
<objectheight="345"width="123'> height='456'width=789>
```

The quotes around the values could be **double**, **single** or **none**. And the words could be put together or there could be one or more whitespaces. And what is important the digits as a value could be anything

So, I need to replace the integervalue in `height="510`" (or `height='123'` or `height=456`) with my own variable `$height_val`.

My code so far:

```
$height_val = "640";
$pattern = ??? // this regex I need to find out
$replacement = $height_val;
$string = '<objectheight="345"width="123\'> height=\'456\'width=789>'
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

And the final result should be `<objectheight="640"width="123\'> height=\'640\'width=789>`

Comment: try not to use preg_replace, and stick to preg_replace_callback

Comment: Always explain why, if possible, thanks.

Comment: @Matthew Baker it's not working for something like: `value="width=650&amp;height=515` Any idea how to fix it. Otherwise your code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reg-ex I'd use is: `height=(["']*)[0-9]*(["']*)`.  This ensures you only get the height value with any non-alpha digit after the equals followed by an any length number.

```
$height_val = "640";
//$pattern = '/height=\D[0-9]*\D/' // pre comments regex
$pattern = height='/(["']*)[0-9]*(["']*)/'; //new regex
$replacement = $height_val;
$string = '<objectheight="345"width="123\'> height=\'456\'width=789>'
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

I've tested it on the following variables:

```
<object height="510"   width="650">height="510"width="650">
<objectheight="510"   width="650">height="510"width="650">
<object height='510'   width="650">height="510"width="650">
<objectheight='510'width="650">height="510"width="650">
value="width=650&amp;height=515&amp;plugins=http://
```

Going forward I would recommend you try using a [RegEx tester](http://regexpal.com) to try your own combinations.  You can also use this [regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to give you help with character classes.

Updated:
If you wish to allow for no quotation marks too use the following:

Comment: It's working well, however it's not working for something like: value="width=650&amp;height=515 Any idea how to fix this little issue, so  Ican select your answer as the right one?

Comment: @Derfder see my answer I updated it with logic for replacing. Should work for all of your cases.

Comment: No, as I said in my previous comment `/height=\D[0-9]*\D/` will not affect something like `value="width=650&amp;height=515&amp;plugins=http://` and `height=515&amp;` will remain intact instead of the correct `mp;height=640&amp;` Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: @Derfder In that case we will need a slightly more complex regex.  I've updated the answer to incorporate a regex which allows for `"'` as selectors, or not... Let me know if any issues.

Comment: @Downvoter: Instead of just down voting please provide an explanation as to why, to assist those reading the post and to help the responder correct the reason.